# Result class name isn't appear on SOAP result

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf, soap, wcf-client

I have a WCF service. I call its methods using SOAP 1.2 with jQuery
I call a method which suppose to return the following class:

```
namespace ConfigComWrapper.ConfigCom
{
    public class CommandResult
    {
        public int ErrorCode = ErrorCodeTypes.OK;
        public string ErrorDescription = string.Empty;

        public CommandResult(){}    
}
```

However the SOAP response returns me only its members without even mentioning the CommandResult class at all. this is a generated xml response(SOAP) in the WCF Test client:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_2">http://www.enghouse.com/CosmoCom/WebAdminAPIServiceLibrary/ITenantAdmin/LoginResponse</a:Action>
    <a:RelatesTo u:Id="_3">urn:uuid:509fa011-0e6a-4370-896b-6d45756a5fa9</a:RelatesTo>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <u:Timestamp u:Id="uuid-71549a1a-6c54-4a76-b224-66bc45877e0f-11">
        <u:Created>2012-10-18T14:30:49.878Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2012-10-18T14:35:49.878Z</u:Expires>
      </u:Timestamp>
      <c:DerivedKeyToken u:Id="uuid-71549a1a-6c54-4a76-b224-66bc45877e0f-7" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc">
        <o:SecurityTokenReference>
          <o:Reference URI="urn:uuid:cf569488-040b-4bcb-8270-b7973c0d6e2a" ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct" />
        </o:SecurityTokenReference>
        <c:Offset>0</c:Offset>
        <c:Length>24</c:Length>
        <c:Nonce>TNFiG8+NqEdgXJ8njmVNPw==</c:Nonce>
      </c:DerivedKeyToken>
      <c:DerivedKeyToken u:Id="uuid-71549a1a-6c54-4a76-b224-66bc45877e0f-8" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc">
        <o:SecurityTokenReference>
          <o:Reference URI="urn:uuid:cf569488-040b-4bcb-8270-b7973c0d6e2a" ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct" />
        </o:SecurityTokenReference>
        <c:Nonce>9dmn1BiWfn0U7cmlbkFWdg==</c:Nonce>
      </c:DerivedKeyToken>
      <e:ReferenceList xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <e:DataReference URI="#_1" />
        <e:DataReference URI="#_4" />
      </e:ReferenceList>
      <e:EncryptedData Id="_4" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <o:SecurityTokenReference>
            <o:Reference ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/dk" URI="#uuid-71549a1a-6c54-4a76-b224-66bc45877e0f-8" />
          </o:SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
        <e:CipherData>
          <e:CipherValue>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</e:CipherValue>
        </e:CipherData>
      </e:EncryptedData>
    </o:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body u:Id="_0">
    <LoginResponse xmlns="http://www.enghouse.com/CosmoCom/WebAdminAPIServiceLibrary">
      <LoginResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ConfigComWrapper.ConfigCom" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:ErrorCode>0</a:ErrorCode>
        <a:ErrorDescription />
      </LoginResult>
    </LoginResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

But for some reason the "Formatted option" in the WCF Test Client shows that CommandResult was returned :
[image]

Some one knows why it lacks the CommandResult class from the SOAP Response ?
Thanks !

Comment: I'm not sure if you've provided us with enough info to answer the question. One stab though: any chance you've been playing with the [IsWrapped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.messagecontractattribute.iswrapped.aspx) attribute?

Answer (score 0):

If you sending a object as a result of a operation call of server side, you have to set your class as [DataContract]. This will help for the serialization of custom classes as per my understanding,
As per your question you have to set it as follow.

```
namespace ConfigComWrapper.ConfigCom
{
    [DataContract]
    public class CommandResult
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int ErrorCode = ErrorCodeTypes.OK;
        [DataMember]
        public string ErrorDescription = string.Empty;
        [DataMember]
        public CommandResult(){}    
}
```

Once you done this update your service reference in your client side. Hope this will help you.